# How to erase git author commit history?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have an internal gitlab repository.

The repository hosts many projects.

Some of those projects are customized external open source projects.

I want the commit history to reflect only commits done internally.

So how can I erase the names of the original authors and their commits so it won't appear on gitlab's analytics history.

Comment: i think thats not appropriate and not intended in git. You can fix commits by ammending them but i think, if you change the authors name, its dishonorable. Its just my opinion.

Comment: I agree with you. I don't want to change their name. I want the analytics to be automatically applied from a certain date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just erased the `.git` file and did a new git init.

The problems with this solution are:

1. it erased all of the git commits that were including some done  by my team.
2. You lose out on all l the original history which you can learn from.

Best to keep a backup.

Answer (score 2):

To remove old commits use `git checkout --orphan`

Example:

Commit history:

```
* 5 History you want to keep
* 4 History you want to keep
* 3 First commit you want to keep
* 2 Commit you want to delete
* 1 Commit you want to delete
```

Git commands:

```
git checkout --orphan new_root 2
git commit -m'truncated history'
git rebase --onto new_root 2 master
git branch -D new_root
```

Replace 2 with the hash of the last commit you want to get rid of.

You'll have to use `git push origin master --force` to update the code on the server. All commits' hashes will be updated, so any feature branches you have will need to be updated.

Answer (score -1):

One of the easiest way to modify git history is [filter branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)

Use something like that, and adapt it to your usage:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
    if test "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "SPECIFIC_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
    then
        GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=nobody
        export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
    fi
' -- --all
```

**Don't forget to make a backup of your repository before, and you'll have to use `push --force` since it changes the commit ids.**